# add custom css to twig template, style not applying

Tags: html, css, symfony, twig

I am trying really hard to somehow link my main.css to my html templates in twig.
Im not sure why its not working properley, and i ran out of ideas.

I have added this line in my `head` block in my base html file.

```
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" {{ source('main.css') }}">
```

This is all i have in my css file

```
body{
   background: red;
}
```

Here is my folder structure

[image]

Comment: Seems to be Symfony 4 right?

Comment: `main.css` should be under `public` dir i guess

Comment: That is not correct path to css, double click on a CSS you want to use, click Properties and go to File Location, copy path and copy to: <link type=“text/css” rel=“stylesheet” href=“HERE”>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

You should create `main.css` in a path relative to `templating` directory.

The problem is `source` is not the thing you are probably after. look at the template below:

**Twig**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" {{ source('main.css') }}">
    </head>
    <body>
        This is Body
    </body>
</html>
```

the produced HTML source in browser is this:

**HTML Source**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" body{ background: red;}">
    </head>
    <body>
        This is Body
    </body>
</html>
```

You are probably after `asset` twig function:

```
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" {{ asset('main.css') }}">
```

Please note that, `asset` gets path relative to `public` directory, so you should put your web assets inside `public`, not `templating`.

If you are using Symfony 4, you should also install symfony/asset:

```
composer require symfony/asset
```

You may read more on this here: [Creating and Using Templates, Linking to Assets](https://symfony.com/doc/current/templating.html#linking-to-assets)